# Windows 10 - Sysprep keeps adding language and keyboard layout

Tags: windows, sysprep, keyboard-layout

I have a very frustrating problem with my sysprep image. Everytime, I choose fr-CA as keyboard layout in my sysprep answerfile, I always end up with canadian french (Multilangual standard), english US and French (France).

I specified in my answer file the inputLocal to: 0c0c:0001109 in winpe, specialize and oobesystem. I also change the value for the copyprofile option to yes.

This problem doesn't happen if I switch to english (canada).

Anyone have an idea what I could do to ONLY have french canada keyboard?

By the way, we don't use SCCM or Audit mode for our Windows system image. We use a vmware VM that is preconfigured with the programs we need and configuration that are persistent through sysprep. Then we send the image to clonezilla for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by our dumbass admin not downloading the good Windows 10 ISO... when you sysprep, it uses the default language of the ISO...